# Forward port 80 to another port

Tags: port-forwarding

I am running a webserver on a RedHat 6 box that I don't have root access to.

Because I need ports 80 and 443, I require root access to start and stop the server. I am not allowed root access, but I am able to ask someone with root access to set something up to forward the ports for me.

So is it possible to forward port 80 to 8080 and port 443 to 8443, so that I am able to start and stop my server without root access?

Comment: There are several ways to do that. You could redirect the ports with iptables or set up an Apache proxy which would run on 80 and 443 and redirect the requests on another web server listening on 8080 and 8443.

Comment: Another method would be to get sudo access allowing you only to run `service httpd restart`.